# How do I provide one-time access to a downloads page to anonymous users?

Tags: navigation

Our company wants to have a secured downloads area for software.  We want to send a link to a customer via email, after they have purchased a license for the software.  We don't want to create a site account for every customer; we just want them to click the link to get one-time access to the downloads page.  All the modules I have seen for one-time use links either assume that the link is something used for password reset, etc., or the module is not ready for prime-time.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write a new module. One of the modules that I referred to as "not ready for prime-time" is a module called ["Deep link"](http://drupal.org/project/deeplink). I had said that because there seemed to be some bugs with the use of one-time-only links. After looking at the code for a few days, I was able to fix a couple issues and submitted patches back to the project page. The module now works well enough to suit my purpose, and I would recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

You need write a module to do this job, 
I wrote a module that do something like this ( count download times )

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_menu();
*/
function bicuk_downloadounter_menu() {

    $items=array();
    $items['download/%']=array(
        'title' => 'increase Download counter ',
        'description' => t('callback url for increse Downloading count'),
        'page callback' => 'downloadcounter_tickup',
        'page arguments' =>array(1),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access callback' =>true,

    );
    return $items;
}

/* call back function to increase counter
 * @param $fid , file id 
 */
function downloadcounter_tickup($fid){

   if(!is_numeric($fid)) 
              drupal_goto();
   $file=file_load($fid);
   if(!isset($file->fid))
            drupal_goto();
   $acceptable_ext=unserialize(variable_get('bicuk_downloadounter_valid_extensions'));
   $file_path=file_create_url($file->uri);
   $pathinfo=  pathinfo($file_path);
   $extension=$pathinfo['extension'];
 if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $acceptable_ext))
             drupal_goto();
   $query=  db_select('bicuk_downloadcounter_counter','bdc')->fields('bdc',array('count'));
   $query->condition('fid',$fid, '=');
   $count=$query->execute()->fetchField();
if($count)
{
    $query=  db_update('bicuk_downloadcounter_counter')->fields(array('count'=>$count+1));
    $query->condition('fid',$fid, '=');
    $query->execute(); 
}
else
  {
    $query=  db_insert('bicuk_downloadcounter_counter')->fields(array('name','count','fid'),array($file->filename,1,$fid));
    $query->execute();
  }
   drupal_goto($file_path);
}

/**
 *
 * @param type $fid fid
 * @return type int count
 */

function downloadcounter_get($fid){
   $query=  db_select('bicuk_downloadcounter_counter','bdc')->fields('bdc',array('count'));
   $query->condition('fid',$fid, '=');
   $count=$query->execute()->fetchField();
   return $count;
}
```

**you can  get idea from this code to achieve your job,instead of counting download time try to check downlading time by IP and do your limitation**

Comment: Thanks ! Did you have to create new tables/databases to activate this ?